# How can I access this json data using angular js

Tags: angularjs, json

### Im trying to access this json data using ng-repeat in angular. But I data does not come to the view.

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="product in Brands track by $index">

                        <label>{{product.ID}}</label>
                        <label style="margin-right: 10px;">{{product.Name}}</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.Selected" ng-true-value='"Y"'
                               ng-false-value='"N"' value="{{product.Name}}" style="margin-right: 10px;" cd-true-value="'{{product.ID}}'" cd-false-value="'None'" />
```

---

This is a part of json data

```
Object {SelectFromDate: Thu Apr 07 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 , ToDate: Fri Apr 15 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 , Selected: "1"}
    {"data":[{"ID":1,"BrandID":1,"ProductID":1,"Name":"***","Created":"****"},{"ID":2,"BrandID":2,"ProductID":1,"Name":"***","Created":"****"},{"ID":3,"BrandID":3,"ProductID":1,"Name":"***","Created":"****"},{"ID":4,"BrandID":4,"ProductID":1,"Name":"***","Created":"****""},    {"ID":5,"BrandID":5,"ProductID":1,"Name":"***","Created":"****"},
```

---

this is the controller

```
$scope.submit = function() {
        console.log($scope.formData);


            angularService.PostAngularFormData($scope.formData).then(function (response) {
                $scope.Brands = JSON.stringify(response);
                console.log($scope.Brands);

            });
```

Comment: Can you provide " console.log(response) " console log out put ?

Comment: the part I have shown as json data is the console.log responce

Comment: Can you provide " console.log(response) " console log all out put ? I try my self

Comment: when I try to log responce this error occurs

Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)

Comment: @Amila Thank you so much for your support. When I used angular.fromJson instel of JSON.stringify it worked. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
$scope.allResponse = JSON.parse(response);
$scope.brands = $scope.allResponse.data;
console.log($scope.brands);
```

or use

```
$scope.brands = angular.fromJson(response.data);
console.log($scope.brands);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But when I use this I get the following error

'angular.js:13294 SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)

Comment: Can you provide " console.log(response) " console log out put ?

Comment: the part I have shown as json data is the console.log responce

Comment: you have misspelled the 'Brands' is 'Brandss'

Comment: if you wants to products then use `$scope.allResponse = JSON.parse(response);  $scope.products = $scope.allResponse.data;` you will get an array of products in `$scope.products`. use it in `ng-repeat`

Comment: or use  `$scope.Brands = JSON.parse(response.data);` this will work

Comment: It gives "Undefined" as well

Comment: OMG It works. Thank you so much @Devidas. You just made my day. I was going at it for most of the day. This answer solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Modify controller

```
angularService.PostAngularFormData($scope.formData).then(function (response) {
        $scope.Brands = response.data; 
        console.log($scope.Brands);

    });
```

Try it and give console out put

Comment: [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object
3
:
Object
4
:
Object
5
:
Object
6
:
Object
7
:
Object
8
:
Object
9
:
Object
10
:
Object
11
:
Object
12
:
Object
13
:
Object
14
:
Object
15
:
Object
16
:
Object
17
:
Object
18
:
Object
19
:
Object
20
:
Object'

Comment: I have been using ng-repeat to get data

Comment: ng-repeat="brand in Brands track by $index" <-- use and get result

Comment: When I use that I only get a large blank space in the view. No text or data visible

Comment: If  ng-repeat="brand in Brands" and inside ng-repeat div use {{brand}}, What is view out come?

Comment: { 
" 
d 
a 
t 
a 
" 
: 
[ 
{ 
" 
I 
D 
" 
: 
1 
, 
" 
B 
r 
a 
n 
d 
I 
D 
" 
: 
1 
, 
" 
P 
r 
o 
d 
u 
c 
t 
I 
D 
" 
: 
1 
, 
" 
N 
a 
m 
e 
" 
: 
" 
*
* 
* 
" 
, 
" 
C 
r 
e 
a 
t 
e 
d 
" 
: 
" 
2 
* 
* 
*  
" 
} 
, 
{ 
" 
I 
D 
" 
: 
2 
, 
" 
B 
r 
a 
n 
d 
I 
D 
" 
: 
2 
, 
" 
P 

the whole console.log output goes down single character by character

Comment: Change your controller code one line as -> var arrayOfData = response.data.data; || now what is out come ?

Comment: like adding <br/> tag after each character

Comment: Responce on console log is "Undefined"

Comment: Now I'll update my answer again, Try it may be help you

Comment: No it doesnt work either. It says unexpected token o error

Answer (score 0):

Modify controller

```
// I assume you result array 
var array = {"data":[{"ID":1,"BrandID":1,"ProductID":1,"Name":"RI","Created":"2016-04-11T23:‌​19:03.463"},
                 {"ID":2,"BrandID":2,"ProductID":1,"Name":"BLE","Created":"2016-04-11T‌​23:19:03.48"} ]};

$scope.brands = array.data;
```

Inside view

```
<div ng-repeat="brand in brands">
    {{brand}}
</div>
```

my View out put

```
{"ID":1,"BrandID":1,"ProductID":1,"Name":"RI","Created":"2016-04-11T23:‌​19:03.463"}
{"ID":2,"BrandID":2,"ProductID":1,"Name":"BLE","Created":"2016-04-11T‌​23:19:03.48"}
```

Try it and solve your problem

Comment: Thanks @Amila. I will try this too. angular.fromJson solved this too. Thanks again